# How do I unpack DEC3N & UDEC3 format?

Tags: 3d, unpack, normals

I have a small tool that I use to convert some mesh files. The mesh files have the normal's stored in either DEC3N or UDEC3 format. How do I unpack that to three regular floats cpu side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is explained here:
http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/OES/OES_vertex_type_10_10_10_2.txt

```
Modifications to table 2.9 (Component conversions)

    Add the following entries:

        GLType                     Conversion of (x, y, z)  Conversion of w
        -------                    ----------------------   ===============
        INT_10_10_10_2_OES        (2c + 1)/(2^10 - 1)       (2c + 1)/(2^2 - 1)
        UNSIGNED_10_10_10_2_OES    c / (2^10 - 1)            c / (2^2 - 1)
```

So if you have normal in 32-bit variable N with UDEC3 format, then

```
x = (float)( (N>>22) / ((1<<10) - 1);
y = (float)( ((N>>12) & ((1<<10)-1)) / ((1<<10) - 1);
z = (float)( ((N>>2)  & ((1<<10)-1)) / ((1<<10) - 1);
```

Most likely you'll want to unpack also w, and divide xyz with w.

Comment: I'm curious about why he should do this: "Most likely you'll want to unpack also w, and divide xyz with w." He asked about *normals*, which are most certainly not stored in homogenous coordinates.

Comment: Of course. But what if w contains value -1. No idea who generates DEC3N and UDEC3 formats, but I would do that. Just in case. I don't trust 3rd party tools to do "the right thing" and not to abuse the specified format.